How to get purchase on an interior mechanism for sliding doors that's been rounded ~smooth?
I have these big sliding glass doors/windows. 8' tall, 6' wide. They hang and glide on a track from above, but to prevent air drafts coming in the bottom they can drop down to make a seal on the ground. They are heavy.

To raise the doors for moving, they must be lifted up. To lift them, a special handle is inserted into a hole on each and rotated 180°. The end of the handle that is inserted is square, but (from the factory) rounded on the edges of the shaft, and rounded on the very end. The shaft is 3/8" x 3/8", and overall reaches back about 2".



Over 20 years, the handle has slowly beat up the inside of the door mechanism. What used to be a ~square hole in each that the handle fit into has now been made almost completely round. The handle slips and no longer can lift the doors.




The last time they were opened, the only way we were able to use the handle to get them lowered was to remove the black plastic bushing around the hole so that the handle could get in just a little deeper and find purchase on a bit of metal that had not already been rounded. (We broke the plastic in one case, as seen.) That little bit of metal is likely not good enough to get them lifted—lifting is harder than lowering—and will surely get smoothed off quickly also.
Does anyone have any ideas for how to hack the interior of the mechanism so that something—not necessarily the factory handle—can be used to rotate it again? Inserting a tiny hacksaw blade, paintstakingly cutting a couple notches despite no room to work, and then using an enormous flat-head screwdriver with a long wrench on the handle? Some way to fill the hole with a putty that becomes incredibly strong, but that would not stick to the back wall (and thus freeze the mechanism)?
I'm open to creative ideas.

Just to be clear, removing the mechanisms is not an option? That would allow for more repair choices as well as an opportunity to clean and lubricate the pieces/parts so as to place less stress on the repair.

Usually something like that needs replacement or a rebuild.  Most of what you suggest might work once or twice.  Both pieces will need work to match/fit back up.

@HABO I have not yet been able to figure how to access them. Eventually that will almost certainly be necessary, but I fear it may involve a complete disassembly. Right now I'm looking for any hack to reach in there and rotate, given that I want them opened for a graduation party in 6 days.

Wedging something in between the shaft and the hole like a hacksaw/jigsaw blade/s might be enough.  A locksmith might be able to get replacement parts.  It looks a lot like the inside of a door knob/latch.  I am guessing you just pull up/push down(turn just a bit) and do not crank.

Another idea could be to use a Dremel with a small grinding bit to re-square the corners of the hole, and have a welder add some material to the shaft of the handle.  You'd probably have to file/sand it back down a little bit to make it fit.
